# Avalon Dock Auto hide panel will not reopen

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, avalondock

I have a .NET 6.0 program that uses Xceed Avalon Dock 2.0. I have an 'AnchorableSource' set to a `BindableCollection` of ViewModels and currently have a single view model in the collection. My issue is that when I AutoHide the panel, it collapses to the botton, but it will not reopen when I click on the title.

[image: Auto Hide]

Collapses to:

[image: Hidden]

But when I click "Tools" nothing happens.

I'm not sure where to put a breakpoint or if I can add some code behind to catch the click and reopen.  I have another project that uses the same thing and it reopens just fine.

Here is my code:

**MainView.xaml**

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="GUI.Core.Views.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:cal="http://caliburnmicro.com"
        xmlns:avalonDock="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"
        xmlns:avalonDock1="clr-namespace:GUI.Resources" 
        xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:GUI.Core.ViewModels" 
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodels:MainViewModel}"
        Icon="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/Icon.png"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="GUI" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" IsManipulationEnabled="True" SaveWindowPosition="True">
    <Grid Margin="0 0 0 5">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/BGPATTERN.png" TileMode="Tile" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Background="{StaticResource MenuBrush}" CanVerticallyScroll="True" CanHorizontallyScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MenuTextStyle}" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDown] = [Action MenuItemClick('ModeSelection')]" Text="Mode Selection" />
                <TextBlock Margin="3" Foreground="White" Opacity="0.5" Text="|" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MenuTextStyle}" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDown] = [Action MenuItemClick('Load')]" Text="Load" />
                <TextBlock Margin="3" Foreground="White" Opacity="0.5" Text="|" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MenuTextStyle}" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDown] = [Action MenuItemClick('FaultLog')]" Text="Fault Log" />
                <TextBlock Margin="3" Foreground="White" Opacity="0.5" Text="|" />
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MenuTextStyle}" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDown] = [Action MenuItemClick('Health')]" Text="Health" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="dockingManager"
                                   cal:Message.Attach="[Event DocumentClosing] = [Action DocumentClosingListener($eventArgs)];
                                                       [Event DocumentClosed] = [Action DocumentClosedListener()]"
                                   AnchorablesSource="{Binding Tools}"
                                   DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}"
                                   ActiveContent="{Binding ActiveDocument, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                   Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="14" Background="{x:Null}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" ClipToBounds="True" Margin="0 0 3 0">
            <avalonDock:DockingManager.Theme>
                <avalonDock:MetroTheme />
            </avalonDock:DockingManager.Theme>
            <avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDock:LayoutItem}">
                    <Setter Property="CanClose" Value="{Binding Model.CanClose, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
                    <Setter Property="IsActive" Value="{Binding Model.IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </Style>
            </avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
            <avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
                <avalonDock1:AutobinderTemplateSelector>
                    <avalonDock1:AutobinderTemplateSelector.Template>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding . }" IsTabStop="False" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </avalonDock1:AutobinderTemplateSelector.Template>
                </avalonDock1:AutobinderTemplateSelector>
            </avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
            <avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
                <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane/>
                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane DockHeight="250">
                    </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
            </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
        </avalonDock:DockingManager>
    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : Screen, IMainViewModel
{
    IPanelBaseViewModel _activeDocument;
    readonly IOutputViewModel _textOutputViewModel;
    readonly IModeSelectionViewModel _modeSelectionViewModel;
    readonly ILoadViewModel _paLoadViewModel;
    readonly IFaultLogViewModel _faultLogViewModel;
    readonly IHealthViewModel _paHealthViewModel;
    IPanelBaseViewModel _closingDocument;
    string name;

    public BindableCollection<IPanelBaseViewModel> Tools { get; set; }
    public BindableCollection<IPanelBaseViewModel> Documents { get; set; }
    public IPanelBaseViewModel ActiveDocument
    {
        get { return _activeDocument; }
        set { _activeDocument = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ActiveDocument); }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Name); }
    }

    public MainViewModel(IOutputViewModel outputViewModel,
                         IHealthViewModel PAHealthViewModel,
                         IModeSelectionViewModel ModeSelectionViewModel,
                         ILoadViewModel PALoadViewModel,
                         IFaultLogViewModel FaultLogViewModel
                         )
    {
        DisplayName = "Debug GUI v" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
        _paHealthViewModel = PAHealthViewModel;
        _textOutputViewModel = outputViewModel;
        _modeSelectionViewModel = ModeSelectionViewModel;
        _paLoadViewModel = PALoadViewModel;
        _faultLogViewModel = FaultLogViewModel;

        Tools = new BindableCollection<IPanelBaseViewModel> { _textOutputViewModel };
        Documents = new BindableCollection<IPanelBaseViewModel> { };

        MenuItemClick("ModeSelection");
    }

    public void AddDocument(IPanelBaseViewModel pbvm)
    {
        if (!Documents.Contains(pbvm))
        {
            Documents.Add(pbvm);
        }
        ActiveDocument = pbvm;
    }

    public void DocumentClosingListener(DocumentClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        _closingDocument = (IPanelBaseViewModel)e.Document.Content;
    }

    public void DocumentClosedListener()
    {
        Documents.Remove(_closingDocument);
    }

    public void MenuItemClick(string item)
    {
        switch (item)
        {
            case "ModeSelection":
                AddDocument(_modeSelectionViewModel);
                break;
            case "Load":
                AddDocument(_paLoadViewModel);
                break;
            case "FaultLog":
                AddDocument(_faultLogViewModel);
                break;
            case "Health":
                AddDocument(_paHealthViewModel);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        _textOutputViewModel.IsActive = true;
    }
}
```